# Как правильно получить результат из запроса к MS SQL, записав его в соответствующие переменные?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server, ado.net

Есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM ClientProfile WHERE (ClientProfile.UserID = 1)   (SELECT * FROM   Manager WHERE(Manager.UserID =  1)  )  (SELECT  * FROM Administrator WHERE (Administrator.UserID = 1))
```

В коде программы Windows Forms вместо *нужная таблица.UserID передаётся параметр.
Если выполнить это в MS SQL, получаешь 3 таблицы: 2 пустые, так как там отсутствует пользователь с таким ID, и одна с данными, которые как раз и нужно получить, записав в переменные.

Такова попытка обработать запрос со стороны Visual Studio:

```
SqlCommand GetUserProfile2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ClientProfile WHERE (ClientProfile.UserID =  " + DataBank.CurrentUserID + ")" + "(SELECT * FROM   Manager WHERE(Manager.UserID =  " + DataBank.CurrentUserID + " )  ) " + " (SELECT  * FROM Administrator WHERE (Administrator.UserID = " + DataBank.CurrentUserID + ")  )", sqlConnection);

var reader2 = GetUserProfile2.ExecuteReader();

if (reader2.HasRows)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2));

    while (reader2.Read())
    {
        //if (reader2.GetInt32(0) < 0)
        if (Convert.ToString(reader2["ClientID"]) != "")
        {
            //DataBank.CurrentClientID = Int32.Parse(reader2.GetString(0));
            //DataBank.CurrentClientFullname = Convert.ToString(reader2["ClientFullName"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(reader2["ClientPhoneNumber"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentClientDateOfBirth = Convert.ToString(reader2["CurrentClientDateOfBirth"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentClientEmail = Convert.ToString(reader2["Email"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentClientPassport = Convert.ToString(reader2["Passport"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentClientInternationalPassport = Convert.ToString(reader2["InternationalPassport"]);
            DataBank.CurrentClientID = (reader2.GetInt32(0));
            DataBank.CurrentClientFullname = (reader2.GetString(1));
            DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber = (reader2.GetString(2));
            DataBank.CurrentClientDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(3).ToString();
            DataBank.CurrentClientEmail = reader2.GetString(4);
            DataBank.CurrentClientPassport = (reader2.GetString(5));
            DataBank.CurrentClientInternationalPassport = (reader2.GetString(6));


            Cl.ClientFullNameUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientFullname;
            Cl.ClientPhoneNumberUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber;
            Cl.ClientDateOfBirthUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientDateOfBirth;
            Cl.ClientEmailUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientEmail;
            Cl.ClientPassportUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPassport;
            Cl.ClientInternationalPassportUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientInternationalPassport;
            this.Hide();
            Cl.Show();
        }
        //else if (reader2.GetString(8) != "") 
        else if (Convert.ToString(reader2["ManagerID"]) != "")
        {
            //DataBank.CurrentManagerID = Int32.Parse(reader2.GetString(0));
            //DataBank.CurrentManagerFullname = Convert.ToString(reader2["ManagerFullname"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentManagerEmail = Convert.ToString(reader2["Email"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentManagerPhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(reader2["PhoneNumber"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentManagerDateOfBirth = Convert.ToString(reader2["DateOfBirth"]);
            DataBank.CurrentManagerID = (reader2.GetInt32(8));     //0
            DataBank.CurrentManagerFullname = (reader2.GetString(9));  //1
            DataBank.CurrentManagerEmail = (reader2.GetString(10));          //2
            DataBank.CurrentManagerPhoneNumber = (reader2.GetString(11));            //3
            DataBank.CurrentManagerDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(12).ToString();         //4

            this.Hide();
            Man.Show();
        }

        //else if (reader2.GetString(14)!="")
        else if (Convert.ToString(reader2["AdministratorID"]) != "")
        {
            //DataBank.CurrentAdministratorID = Int32.Parse(reader2.GetString(0));
            //DataBank.CurrentAdministratorFullname = Convert.ToString(reader2["AdministratorFullName"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentAdministratorPhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(reader2["PhoneNumber"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentAdministratorDateOfBirth = Convert.ToString(reader2["DateOfBirth"]);
            //DataBank.CurrentAdministratorEmail = Convert.ToString(reader2["Email"]);
            DataBank.CurrentAdministratorID = (reader2.GetInt32(14));
            DataBank.CurrentAdministratorFullname = (reader2.GetString(15));
            DataBank.CurrentAdministratorEmail = (reader2.GetString(16));
            DataBank.CurrentAdministratorPhoneNumber = (reader2.GetString(17));
            DataBank.CurrentAdministratorDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(18).ToString();

            this.Hide();
            Adm.Show();
        }
        //Requests.Text += (Convert.ToString(reader["RequestId"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(reader["ClientId"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(reader["TourId"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(reader["RequestDate"]) + "       " + Convert.ToString(reader["ManagerId"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(reader["Acceptance"]) + "\n");
    }
}
reader2.Close();
```

При нынешнем коде, проскакивает аутентификация клиента, и его поля успешно считываются. А вот зайти в качестве менеджера или администратора не получается. При отладке явно видны исключения:

> '"reader1.Depth" выдал исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" '"reader1.FieldCount" выдал исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" '"reader1.HasRows" выдал исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" '"reader1.VisibleFieldCount" выдал исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException"

Приведено к виду:

```
        private void SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool loginright = false;
        bool passwordright = false;


        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hzcho\source\repos\Tourist__Office\Tourist__Office\Tourist_office.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Users", sqlConnection);
        sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);


        dataSet = new DataSet();

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Users");

        SqlCommand CheckAuth = new SqlCommand("Authentification", sqlConnection);
        CheckAuth.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = AuthLogin.Text;
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text);
        //CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@Answer", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";

        string login = AuthLogin.Text;
        string password = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text).ToLower();

        var answer = new SqlParameter("@Answer", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        answer.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        answer.Size = 64;
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add(answer);

        CheckAuth.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var res = answer.Value.ToString();

        {
            if ((res == "Отсутствует в базе"))
            //if (Int32.Parse(reader.GetString(0)) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Отсутствует в базе");
            }
            else if ((res == "Присутствует в базе"))
            {
                loginright = true;
                passwordright = true;
                //MessageBox.Show("Отсутствует в базе");
                SqlCommand GetIdUser = new SqlCommand("SELECT IdUser from Users Where Login = '" + login + "'" + " AND Password = '" + password + "'", sqlConnection);
                //sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter
                //dataSet = new DataSet();

                //using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    //connection.Open();
                    //SqlCommand FillRequests = new SqlCommand("ShowAllRequests", connection);
                    //FillRequests.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    // указываем, что команда представляет хранимую процедуру
                    //SqlCommand GetUserProfile1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT IdUser from Users Where Login =" + AuthLogin.Text + " AND Password = " + Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text), sqlConnection);

                    var reader1 = GetIdUser.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader1.HasRows)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2));

                        while (reader1.Read())
                        {
                            DataBank.CurrentUserID = (reader1.GetInt32(0));
                        }
                    }
                    reader1.Close();

                    string GetProfileData = "SELECT * FROM ClientProfile WHERE ClientProfile.UserID = @UserId  " +
                   "SELECT * FROM Manager       WHERE Manager.UserID       = @UserId  " +
                   "SELECT * FROM Administrator WHERE Administrator.UserID = @UserId";
                    using (var GetUserProfile = new SqlCommand(GetProfileData, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        GetUserProfile.Parameters.Add("UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DataBank.CurrentUserID;

                        using (var reader2 = GetUserProfile.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader2.Read())
                            {
                                DataBank.CurrentClientID = reader2.GetInt32(0);
                                DataBank.CurrentClientFullname = reader2.GetString(1);
                                DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber = reader2.GetString(2);
                                DataBank.CurrentClientDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(3).ToString();
                                DataBank.CurrentClientEmail = reader2.GetString(4);
                                DataBank.CurrentClientPassport = reader2.GetString(5);
                                DataBank.CurrentClientInternationalPassport = reader2.GetString(6);

                                Cl.ClientFullNameUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientFullname;
                                Cl.ClientPhoneNumberUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber;
                                Cl.ClientDateOfBirthUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientDateOfBirth;
                                Cl.ClientEmailUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientEmail;
                                Cl.ClientPassportUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPassport;
                                Cl.ClientInternationalPassportUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientInternationalPassport;
                                this.Hide();
                                Cl.Show();
                            }


                            if (reader2.NextResult()) // move to Manager data
                            {
                                while (reader2.Read())
                                {
                                    // Обратите внимание: индексы колонок снова с нуля
                                    DataBank.CurrentManagerID = reader2.GetInt32(0);
                                    DataBank.CurrentManagerFullname = reader2.GetString(1);
                                    DataBank.CurrentManagerEmail = reader2.GetString(2);
                                    DataBank.CurrentManagerPhoneNumber = reader2.GetString(3);
                                    DataBank.CurrentManagerDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(4).ToString();

                                    Man.ManagerFullName.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientFullname;
                                    Man.ManagerPhoneNumber.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber;
                                    Man.ManDateOfBirth.SetDate(reader2.GetDateTime(4));
                                    Man.ManagerEmail.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientEmail;
                                    this.Hide();
                                    Man.Show();
                                }
                            }

                            if (reader2.NextResult()) // move to Administrator data
                            {
                                while (reader2.Read())
                                {
                                    // Обратите внимание: индексы колонок снова с нуля
                                    DataBank.CurrentAdministratorID = reader2.GetInt32(0);
                                    DataBank.CurrentAdministratorFullname = reader2.GetString(1);
                                    DataBank.CurrentAdministratorEmail = reader2.GetString(2);
                                    DataBank.CurrentAdministratorPhoneNumber = reader2.GetString(3);
                                    DataBank.CurrentAdministratorDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(4).ToString();

                                    //DataBank.CurrentManagerID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                    //DataBank.CurrentManagerFullname = reader.GetString(1);
                                    //DataBank.CurrentManagerEmail = reader.GetString(2);
                                    //DataBank.CurrentManagerPhoneNumber = reader.GetString(3);
                                    //DataBank.CurrentManagerDateOfBirth = reader.GetDateTime(4).ToString();

                                    Adm.UpdAdministratorFullName.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientFullname;
                                    Adm.UpdAdministratorPhoneNumber.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber;
                                    Adm.AdmDateOfB.SetDate(reader2.GetDateTime(4));
                                    Adm.UpdAdministratorEmail.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientEmail;
                                    this.Hide();
                                    Adm.Show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        //sqlConnection.Close();
        if (!loginright || !passwordright)
            MessageBox.Show("Неправильный логин или пароль");
    }
```

Результат: при вводе логина и пароля, перехода на другую форму(Cl,Man,Adm), не происходит, ни на одну из точек остановки при отладке не реагирует. При старом коде переходил на форму клиента(Cl).

Вынес отдельно функции проверки на наличие пользователя в базе и получения его ID, вызываю их в обработчике кнопки. Код всё так же не отрабатывает: игнорирует точки остановки, перехода на другие формы не происходит.

```
        private String IsInBase()
    {


        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hzcho\source\repos\Tourist__Office\Tourist__Office\Tourist_office.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Users", sqlConnection);
        sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);


        dataSet = new DataSet();

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Users");

        SqlCommand CheckAuth = new SqlCommand("Authentification", sqlConnection);
        CheckAuth.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = AuthLogin.Text;
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text);
        //CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@Answer", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";

        string login = AuthLogin.Text;
        string password = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text).ToLower();

        var answer = new SqlParameter("@Answer", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        answer.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        answer.Size = 64;
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add(answer);

        CheckAuth.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var res = answer.Value.ToString();
        return res;
    }


    private void GetIdUser()
    {
        string login = AuthLogin.Text;
        string password = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text).ToLower();
        //MessageBox.Show("Отсутствует в базе");
        SqlCommand GetIdUser = new SqlCommand("SELECT IdUser from Users Where Login = '" + login + "'" + " AND Password = '" + password + "'", sqlConnection);
        //sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter
        //dataSet = new DataSet();

        //using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            //connection.Open();
            //SqlCommand FillRequests = new SqlCommand("ShowAllRequests", connection);
            //FillRequests.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // указываем, что команда представляет хранимую процедуру
            //SqlCommand GetUserProfile1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT IdUser from Users Where Login =" + AuthLogin.Text + " AND Password = " + Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text), sqlConnection);

            var reader1 = GetIdUser.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader1.HasRows)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2));

                while (reader1.Read())
                {
                    DataBank.CurrentUserID = (reader1.GetInt32(0));
                }
            }
            reader1.Close();

        }
    }

    private void SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //bool loginright = false;
        //bool passwordright = false;
        bool loginright = false;
        bool passwordright = false;

        string login = AuthLogin.Text;
        string password = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text).ToLower();

        //string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hzcho\source\repos\Tourist__Office\Tourist__Office\Tourist_office.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        //sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        //sqlConnection.Open();

        //sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Users", sqlConnection);
        //sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);


        //dataSet = new DataSet();

        //sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Users");

        //SqlCommand CheckAuth = new SqlCommand("Authentification", sqlConnection);
        //CheckAuth.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = AuthLogin.Text;
        //CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text);
        ////CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@Answer", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";

        //string login = AuthLogin.Text;
        //string password = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text).ToLower();

        //var answer = new SqlParameter("@Answer", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        //answer.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        //answer.Size = 64;
        //CheckAuth.Parameters.Add(answer);

        //CheckAuth.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //var res = answer.Value.ToString();
        var res = IsInBase();

        {
            if ((res == "Отсутствует в базе"))
            //if (Int32.Parse(reader.GetString(0)) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Отсутствует в базе");
            }
            else if ((res == "Присутствует в базе"))
            {
                GetIdUser();

                string ProfileData = "SELECT * FROM ClientProfile WHERE ClientProfile.UserID = @UserId  " +
               "SELECT * FROM Manager       WHERE Manager.UserID       = @UserId  " +
               "SELECT * FROM Administrator WHERE Administrator.UserID = @UserId";

                using (var GetUserProfile = new SqlCommand(ProfileData, sqlConnection))
                {
                    GetUserProfile.Parameters.Add("UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DataBank.CurrentUserID;

                    using (var reader2 = GetUserProfile.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader2.Read())
                        {
                            DataBank.CurrentClientID = reader2.GetInt32(0);
                            DataBank.CurrentClientFullname = reader2.GetString(1);
                            DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber = reader2.GetString(2);
                            DataBank.CurrentClientDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(3).ToString();
                            DataBank.CurrentClientEmail = reader2.GetString(4);
                            DataBank.CurrentClientPassport = reader2.GetString(5);
                            DataBank.CurrentClientInternationalPassport = reader2.GetString(6);

                            Cl.ClientFullNameUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientFullname;
                            Cl.ClientPhoneNumberUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber;
                            Cl.ClientDateOfBirthUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientDateOfBirth;
                            Cl.ClientEmailUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientEmail;
                            Cl.ClientPassportUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPassport;
                            Cl.ClientInternationalPassportUpd.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientInternationalPassport;
                            this.Hide();
                            Cl.Show();
                        }


                        if (reader2.NextResult()) // move to Manager data
                        {
                            while (reader2.Read())
                            {
                                // Обратите внимание: индексы колонок снова с нуля
                                DataBank.CurrentManagerID = reader2.GetInt32(0);
                                DataBank.CurrentManagerFullname = reader2.GetString(1);
                                DataBank.CurrentManagerEmail = reader2.GetString(2);
                                DataBank.CurrentManagerPhoneNumber = reader2.GetString(3);
                                DataBank.CurrentManagerDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(4).ToString();

                                Man.ManagerFullName.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientFullname;
                                Man.ManagerPhoneNumber.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber;
                                Man.ManDateOfBirth.SetDate(reader2.GetDateTime(4));
                                Man.ManagerEmail.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientEmail;
                                this.Hide();
                                Man.Show();
                            }
                        }

                        if (reader2.NextResult()) // move to Administrator data
                        {
                            while (reader2.Read())
                            {
                                // Обратите внимание: индексы колонок снова с нуля
                                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorID = reader2.GetInt32(0);
                                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorFullname = reader2.GetString(1);
                                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorEmail = reader2.GetString(2);
                                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorPhoneNumber = reader2.GetString(3);
                                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorDateOfBirth = reader2.GetDateTime(4).ToString();

                                //DataBank.CurrentManagerID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                //DataBank.CurrentManagerFullname = reader.GetString(1);
                                //DataBank.CurrentManagerEmail = reader.GetString(2);
                                //DataBank.CurrentManagerPhoneNumber = reader.GetString(3);
                                //DataBank.CurrentManagerDateOfBirth = reader.GetDateTime(4).ToString();

                                Adm.UpdAdministratorFullName.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientFullname;
                                Adm.UpdAdministratorPhoneNumber.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber;
                                Adm.AdmDateOfB.SetDate(reader2.GetDateTime(4));
                                Adm.UpdAdministratorEmail.Text = DataBank.CurrentClientEmail;
                                this.Hide();
                                Adm.Show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            //sqlConnection.Close();
            if (!loginright || !passwordright)
                MessageBox.Show("Неправильный логин или пароль");

        }

           
  }
```

Comment: Вот эта байда `Convert.ToString(reader2["PhoneNumber"]);` не нужна, т.к. у ридера есть метод `GetString()` и есть еще `GetInt32()` и т.д.

Comment: Я ещё раз скажу: разбейте проблему на части. Сейчас ваш код в `SignIn_Click` выполняет слишком много обязанностей. Разбейте его на отдельные методы. В этом вопросе оставьте лишь то, на что я давал ответ. Вынесите этот код в отдельный метод. И давайте отладим его.

Comment: Запросом `SELECT * from Users` вы получаете всю таблицу из БД в DataSet. А затем другими запросами вы опять обращаетесь к этой же таблице в БД. Зачем? Ведь данные уже в датасете: читайте прямо из него.

Comment: Тут должно быть 4 (или 3?) метода: получение данных из таблицы Users, запрос аутентификации с помощью хранимки, повторный запрос того же самого с помощью простого sql-запроса (стоп, что-то одно лишнее, не находите?), а потом метод с кодом пакетного запроса.

Comment: `GetUserProfile` - плохое название для _переменной_. Get - глагол. Это название для _метода_. Переменная в общем случае должна называться существительным. Аналогично `GetProfileData `.

Comment: Cl, Man, Adm - за такие названия в приличном обществе ногами бьют.

Comment: И вообще, раз возникли проблемы со сложным запросом, разбейте его на более простые. Три отдельных селекта. И каждый в отдельном методе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете batch - пакет запросов. Для получения доступа к следующему набору данных нужно использовать метод [NextResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Вы же использовали параметры при работе с хранимой процедурой, почему не используете здесь?

Ресурсы надо освобождать. Я показал, как это делать, применив оператор `using`.
`SqlConnection` тоже нужно освобождать. Но оно, похоже, создаётся у вас где-то в другом месте (обычно это неправильно).

В целом код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
string sql =
    "SELECT * FROM ClientProfile WHERE ClientProfile.UserID = @UserId; " +
    "SELECT * FROM Manager       WHERE Manager.UserID       = @UserId; " +
    "SELECT * FROM Administrator WHERE Administrator.UserID = @UserId";

using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DataBank.CurrentUserID;

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DataBank.CurrentClientID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            DataBank.CurrentClientFullname = reader.GetString(1);
            DataBank.CurrentClientPhoneNumber = reader.GetString(2);
            DataBank.CurrentClientDateOfBirth = reader.GetDateTime(3);
            DataBank.CurrentClientEmail = reader.GetString(4);
            DataBank.CurrentClientPassport = reader.GetString(5);
            DataBank.CurrentClientInternationalPassport = reader.GetString(6);

            // тут остальной код
        }

        if (reader.NextResult()) // move to Manager data
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Обратите внимание: индексы колонок снова с нуля
                DataBank.CurrentManagerID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                DataBank.CurrentManagerFullname = reader.GetString(1);
                DataBank.CurrentManagerEmail = reader.GetString(2);
                DataBank.CurrentManagerPhoneNumber = reader.GetString(3);
                DataBank.CurrentManagerDateOfBirth = reader.GetDateTime(4);

                // ...
            }
        }

        if (reader.NextResult()) // move to Administrator data
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Обратите внимание: индексы колонок снова с нуля
                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorFullname = reader.GetString(1);
                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorEmail = reader.GetString(2);
                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorPhoneNumber = reader.GetString(3);
                DataBank.CurrentAdministratorDateOfBirth = reader.GetDateTime(4);

                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В действии я код не проверял. Надеюсь, сможете одолеть нюансы.

Comment: Переписал всё к виду, указал в правке.

Comment: @VLADISLAV - отредактируйте свой вопрос, а не мой ответ. PS: в программировании нет понятия "не проскакивает" - есть точное описание проблемы и/или конкретная ошибка/исключение.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не туда нажал, а заметил уже поздно.

Comment: Разделил частично код, но не помогло, @Alexander Petrov .

Comment: Вы знаете, что сейчас решило проблему? Я просто создал ещё один обработчик нажатия по кнопке, который был автоматически подписан как Click_1, скопировал в него код из первого, и теперь всё работает.